# How to assign value to form tag from user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a form tag in the main webpage (aspx file) for a site.  This form tag wraps a user control.  This user control calls several other controls, which is where all the work gets done.  In one of the sub user controls, I need to display several form input boxes.  These input boxes need to have their own unique form action URL

How do I assign an action URL to the parent form tag from one of the sub user controls?

Comment: If your user control is known to be included in the form.. why not just set the action from there to begin with? Also: client-side script is all I can think of for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the parent form programmatically using this code below.

```
HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
frm = (HtmlForm)Page.FindControl("Form1");
frm.Enctype = "multipart/form-data";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your scenario but this worked for me:
Using HTML5 each of your input boxes can have their own unique form action URL. HTML5 `formaction` attribute overrides the action attribute of the main form.